# VBScript, Network folder resscource

Tags: networking, vbscript, directory

I want to try to automatically generate a network folder shortcut. Can I do this with a VBScript?

I found [this tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49210-network-folder-shortcut-create.html), but it only creates a normal shortcut

First try:

```
 Dim sh As New Shell32.Shell
 Dim fld As Shell32.Folder = sh.NameSpace("C:\")
 ' Schließen des Streams nicht vergessen(angehängtes .Close())

 IO.File.Create("C:\obj.lnk").Close() 
 Dim fi As Shell32.FolderItem = fld.ParseName("obj.lnk")
 If fi.IsLink Then
     Dim slo As Shell32.ShellLinkObject = DirectCast(fi.GetLink(), Shell32.ShellLinkObject)
     slo.Path = "C:\folder0" 'Ziel der Verknüpfung
     slo.Description = "Beschreibung"
     slo.Save()
 End If
```

([Source](https://www.vb-paradise.de/index.php/Thread/46128-Ordner-Verkn%C3%BCpfung-erstellen))

Second try:

The solution of this looks similar to the manual way, but the linkpath is always root of the folderpath files :-(

```js
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

linkpath = "C:\Users\freyd\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\MHG_Daten"
folderpath = "\\srv-014\MHG_Daten"
 
if objFSO.Folderexists(linkpath) = false then
 
 set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

 linkcmd = "mklink /D" + " " + """" + linkpath + """" + " " + """" + folderpath + """"
 cmd = "cmd /C " & linkcmd
 WshShell.Run cmd, 4, True

end if
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normal" shortcut?  How does a "normal" shortcut differ from a "network" shortcut?

Comment: http://www.countrykeepers.com/wp/?p=3017 sorry this is the right link... a network folder shortcut looks like a folder created with mklink. But it is shown like a mapped network folder - but without a drive letter